# How to make overlay appear in user's view, even when scrolled?

Tags: html, css, angular

I want the movie overview to pop up, even when I scrolled to the bottom.
Currently it only works when I am at the top of the page.
I have tried sticky, but it did not work.

I want it to be appear in the middle, or somewhere in the screen where the user is able able to see it. When I am at the bottom of the page, the overview still pops up, at the top of the page, outside of the user's view.

Here it works (at the top):

[image: my screenshot which works]

Here it doesn't work:

[image: my screenshot which not working]

```css
.bg {
  background-image:url("../../assets/top.jpg");
  height: 49em;
  width: 103em;
}

.result{
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  background-color: Ivory;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img{
    border-width:5px;
    width:220px;
    height:300px;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

}

.title{
    background-color: Beige ;
    font-size:25px;
    color:DarkOrange;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}

.date{
    font-size:12px;
    color:DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="!_search.movies" class="bg"></div>
<div class="result" *ngIf="_search.movies">
    <div *ngFor="let movie of _search.movies.results">
        <div class="title">{{ movie.title }}<br>
            <div class="container">
                <img class="img" src="{{ _search.imgUrl }}{{ movie.poster_path }}">
              <div class="middle">
                    <div class="text">{{ movie.overview }}</div>
              </div>
              </div>
                <div class='date' >Release Date: {{ movie.release_date }}
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: There are some structural issues noted in your code. Either you can restructure the code or use position: fixed instead of "absolute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the description inside movie box you have to add `position: relative` on your '.title' class like

```
.title{
    position: relative; /* new line */
    background-color: Beige ;
    font-size:25px;
    color:DarkOrange;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! it worked , but the comments are like long rectangle from top to the bottom, how can I style it?

Comment: Because of the description is too long. Its your decision how you represent the long text. you can search the design example on the web and get an idea.